# How to un-nest an array with dictionaries

Tags: nsarray, swift

I dont understand how to "un-nest" this array with dictionaries..?

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("List", ofType: "plist"
var array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as ...

<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Mickey Mouse</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>mickeymouse.png</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: What do you mean? What result are you looking for?

Comment: I thought it had to be declared? ... as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> But can't get it to work

Comment: What do you mean by "un-nest"?

Answer (score 1):

Your `var array` should be typed as:

```
var array : Array<Dictionary<String,String>> = ...
```

Having done that you will be able to access dictionary fields with:

```
array[0]["Image"]
```